# Google Map API v2 grey tiles, everything worked fine (code inside)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, dictionary, tiles

Everything was working fine, the only problem I had is when I change the city to some place south in my country and I get the common "app stopped working problem" but that's fine, I also think what messed this thing up is when I tried to export the application and filled the keystore fields etc.

I searched everywhere on Google and didn't find anything useful, all the solutions I've tried failed so far. Including:
- Creating a whole new project from the beginning with the map only. I still get only grey tiles and no map. (I also tried using MapFragment and not SupportMapFragment)
- I deleted debug.keystore and even default.keyset and generated the API key a few times, still nothing worked.

Here's the code though I don't think there's anything wrong with it:
**The Manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pfetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_pfe"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyDMsGnxt0GrU7Se5arkExJ96uLKqJWmjcQ"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.pfe.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.pfe.Couverture"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I retrieve the map using this on MainActivity in the onCreate() method**

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
</code>
```

Still need a little try catch for this but it was working.

**the layout is like this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/m1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="458dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_row="2"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</GridLayout>
```

I just want to press the compile button and get the map working, so if anyone could help with anything, I'll be very grateful!

Comment: I think the problem is that the map is not loaded from Google's service, so I tried to change the package name aswell and regenerated the key. Still getting no map!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Here's what I did for those who encountered such an issue: I first removed the project and re-imported it onto eclipse, renamed the package completely, deleted the debug.keystore file and rebuilt the project to get a new one then regenerated a new API key and put it into my manifest using the new SHA1 fingerprint.
The thing is that I did all of the above several times without success and decided to leave it for a while and retried to run it every now and then (without touching the source code) and today it just worked so maybe the API key needs some time to function correctly.

Feel free to ask me about any detail if you get the same problem!